# PHPUnit and different class naming convention

Tags: php, phpunit

I have following problem with setting up my phpunit tests. The project I'm working on has different class naming convetion, for example - class name is cMailing and the name of that file is class_mailing.php. How to automate phpunit lookup for that class in my tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bootstrap file for autoloding your classes.

- http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html
- http://jes.st/2011/phpunit-bootstrap-and-autoloading-classes/

Comment: Alternately, include/require the class in the test.